# entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have django project which i am setting up with docker-compose. I went through various blogs and issues on stackoverflow, all pointed the permission issue with entrypoint file and file type. I fixed it, It worked on Linux. But it did not work on Windows 10 and failed with following error

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrypoint.sh\": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Following is my docker file

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
COPY entrypoint.sh /code/
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      wait_hosts: db:5434
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
  
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
```

Entrypoint file

```
#!/bin/sh

# Collect static files
echo "Collect static files"
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Create database migrations
echo "Creating database migrations"
python manage.py makemigrations

# Apply database migrations
echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate

# Start server
echo "Starting server"
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: The `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` overwrite everything your Dockerfile does in `/code`, critically including the `RUN chmod +x` command.  Delete the `volumes:` block.  (It's also better practice to put the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in the Dockerfile so you don't have to specify them every time you run the image.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I am using windows 10 home and docker toolbox. By default, code has to be placed in the C/users. If we want to use any other directory, we have to add the path in the virtual box, shared folder.